# How to call thread on button click and release button

Tags: multithreading, jsf, threadpool, oracle-adf, managed-bean

Excuse me for the title but I have some difficulties explaining my idea within the title. If anyone can edit it, I will be very pleased.

I have a button in my page, when I click that, a managed bean method is called which by its side calls(executes) a new thread. The new thread has to process some operations (I/O, email etc).

The problem is that when I click the button, it remains pressed till all the operations of the thread are finished. Is there a way to just press this button, and then continue doing other stuff, doing these operations in background?

Comment: Hey I meant JSF not C#, @Killercam!

Comment: Sorry, I lost my mind for a second!

Comment: So you just want to start some operation in the background, then display/re-render stuff when the backend task says "I'm done"? Sounds like plain AJAX (ie, `f:ajax` on your `commandButton`) to me.

Comment: Actually not render anything back in front end. I just want to call some processes in background and continue operating in the application without having to wait for those operations to complete. One operation is getting a file from directory and sending it through email.. I do not need to see anything about it. Can you give any idea? Thanks

Comment: Depends on the business service framework you're using. Is it EJB? Then it's merely a matter of putting `@Asynchronous` on the EJB method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is JSF Managed Bean, can you help me with a link?

Comment: Uh yes, a JSF managed bean is just a front end controller which in turn should invoke a business service class/method. Or are you saying that you're mingling the front end controller logic with business service logic in one and same Java class? Why? Separate the concerns! Do you use any business service framework at all? E.g. EJB or Spring.

Comment: I found my problem.. I was calling Thread.run() and not Thread.start(). In that case it wasn't a new thread being created but just some method call. Calling thread with 'start()' works fine. I am using oracle-ADF framework, and the logic is fine but it just was a stupid mistake by me :-/ Thank you for your responses :)

Comment: Manually spawning unmanaged threads in a supposedly lifetime long running Java EE application is recipe for trouble on long term. You should really leverage that job to a self-respected framework such as EJB or Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1

don't span threads. introduce business service with asynchronous operation and invoke that       operation.
--Peddi